# Why normal convergence implies uniform convergence?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Suppose the series $\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}f_n(x)$ converge normaly. Why it converge uniformly ?

**Attempts**

Let $$f(x)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}f_n(x).$$

I know that there is $(u_n)$ s.t. $|f_n(x)|\leq u_n$ and $\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}u_n$ converge. But I don't see how can I get that $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\sup_x \left|\sum_{k=1}^n f_k(x)-f(x)\right|=0.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In view of the definition of $f(x)$ we have 
$$
\left| \sum\limits_{k=1}^n f_k (x) - f(x) \right| = \left| \sum\limits_{k=n+1}^\infty f_k (x)  \right|  \leq \sum\limits_{k=n+1}^\infty |f_k(x)| \leq \sum\limits_{k=n+1}^\infty u_k \to 0  \text{ as } n\to \infty.
$$
The last estimate is independent of $x$, hence the claim.

Comment: very good answer :) thank you very much.(+1)

Comment: glad it helped.

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

To prove that the convergence is uniform at $E$,
By Cauchy

$$(\forall \epsilon>0) \;\; (\exists N\in \Bbb N) : (\forall n\ge N)\;  (\forall p\ge 0) \; : \; (\forall x\in E)$$
$$ \Bigl|\sum_{k=n}^{n+p}f_k(x)\Bigr|<\Bigl| \sum_{k=n}^{n+p}u_k\Bigr|<\epsilon$$

Done.

Comment: doesn't help ! It looks that (seeing @Hayk answer) that you complicate easy things.

Comment: @user601023 This is the IMPORTANT CAUCHY Criterion.

Comment: Even if technically it prove the claim, there is no intuition behind your suggestion !

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding :) (I didn't say that your answer answer is not good, I'm sure it is :)). Just that for me it's very complicated and not intuitive compare to Hayk answer. But it's probably for me only :) And thank you to have taken time to help me, I really appreciate :)

Comment: My answer has the advantage not to use infinity.